# Android app drawer hides

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-screen-shortcuts

It happens on my Samsung Galaxy S4. Here is when the issue happens:

I go to applications and hold & draw an application to any folder. Before I do this, my screen looks like this (I can see the Messaging, Contacts, Phone and Apps icons):

[image: Home screen with bottom app bar]

However once I drag an app from applications screen to any folder, the bottom bar goes away. I am not sure how to get it back. Please note that the apps option is no longer available.

[image]

It gets resolved once I restart the phone. How else to resolve this? If not, at least how to get back my bottom aaps bar once it goes away?

My Android device info:

```
Model number: SAMSUNG-SGH-I337
Android Version: 4.4.4
Baseband Version: I337UCUFNJ4
I am running stock Samsung UI
```

Comment: Not really answering the question – but the simplest solution would be trying an [alternative homescreen/launcher](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_launcher). [Apex](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.anddoes.launcher) and [Nova](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher) are good choices to start with.